# False positive configuration issue reported by VA Scan

Tags: apache, ibm-cloud, rhel, container-registry

We are using an UBI based HTTP server using Apache and our configuration file is located in standard RedHat location `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

In our file, we defined various directives such as following:

```
SSLProtocol TLSv1.2
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM
...
<Files ".ht*">
   Require all denied
</Files>
```

Problem is that Vulnerability Advisor scan is reporting us issues:
- application_configuration:apache.SSLProtocol: Specifies which versions of SSL/TLS protocol are accepted in new connections.
- application_configuration:apache.SSLCipherSuite: Specifies the Cipher Suite that the client is permitted to negotiate in the SSL handshake phase.
- application_configuration:apache.Require -Specifies whether to deny access to .htaccess. This file can contain sensitive site information.

Is this a defect in scanner that is not looking inside standard RHEL paths ?
Is there a way to configure our image to indicate to scanner where our configuration file is?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would include "IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf" at the bottom of httpd.conf and then have a separate file such as: /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf which contains the SSL/TLS settings. I would also suggest using "https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html" to verify ssl/tls settings for external web servers. Example ssl.conf below:

```
    Listen xx.xx.xx.xx:443 https
    ServerName example.com

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

            SSLEngine on
            SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
            SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
            SSLHonorCipherOrder on
            SSLCompression off
            SSLUseStapling on

            SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/server.key
            SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/CAfile.pem

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi,I tested that but the Vulnerability advisor scan is looking inside /etc/apache2/ folders only (then files in /etc/httpd looks ignored in most verifications).

Comment: I would imagine there is a way to change the search directories, or for the sake of the scan you could put a symbolic links to /etc/apache2 if there is nothing there. ex:
"cd /etc"
"ln -s /path/to/real.conf apache2"

Comment: Hi, I moved SSL Directives inside virtual host node (was in server directly before). Now VA Scan is able to see it but still indicating it is a bad value ... Example, SSLProtocol is not set to either of the secure versions, TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2. File: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf But it is detecting I put it Additional Metadata

keypath
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf/VirtualHost[2]/directive[7]
value
TLSv1.2